# Нет панельки в sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Что-то случилось, и теперь у меня нет панельки (которая показывает открытые файлы) сверху под menu с *File, Edit...*. Была у кого такая проблема? И как ее решили? **Show tabs не работает**

[image: скрин]

Comment: `View` → `Show Tabs`. Помогло? Если нет, дальше пойдём.

Comment: нет. Кнопка кликабельна, но не потом ничего не меняется. Всегда написано `Show Tabs`, несмотря сколько раз нажимал

Comment: Папку с проектом перетащите в редактор

Comment: @Elena Да, я знаю, что есть такая штука, но мне не она нужна.

Comment: Что происходит, когда Вы открываете файлы в Sublime Text?

Comment: Забыл написать. Проблема появилась, после того, как нажал `ctrl+shift+s`, с целью использовать 'Сохранить как..'

Comment: @СашаЧерных открывается поверх предыдущего

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я сдался и переустановил его. Но все равно спасибо за помощь